# Restrict API users sign in from Web Admin Portal

Tags: laravel

My Laravel application has an API(students) and a web portal(admins). students register via API. Admin users are generated by a super admin. They login via the admin portal. App\User model has been used to facilitate both types of users with the Spatie Laravel Roles and Permissions.

```js
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
]
```

The problem is that the users who registered from the API can login via Web portal. But after login they cannot do anything because the web routes are having a role based middleware.

```js
// web.php routes

Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('classes', 'WEB\ClassController');
    Route::resource('teachers', 'WEB\TeacherController');
});

// api.php routes

Route::post('register', 'API\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('login', 'API\LoginController@login');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
    Route::resource('papers', 'API\PaperController');
    Route::resource('marks', 'API\MarkController');
});
```

What can I do to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You could either display a message after login to tell students you don't have the permission to access the resource, or you could put the middleware on your web login route, so they can't even access the login page and see a 401 error right away

Comment: But the login page is a public page. My initial thought was to handle it in the authentication process.

Comment: you could still use the idea of middleware, pass a variable to the blade, if the user is a student, show a message on the login page